# openssl create rsa key pair in C and export it

Tags: c, openssl, export, rsa

I want to create a RSA key pair in C/C++ and export it to a string to work with it.

I managed to create the key

```
rsa = RSA_generate_key(bits, exp, NULL, NULL);
if(RSA_check_key(rsa)!=1){
    std::cout << "Error while checking key" << std::endl << std::flush;
}

pkey = EVP_PKEY_new();
EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(pkey, rsa);
```

From this point I can write the private and public key to a file with PEM_write_PUBKEY() and PEM_write_PrivateKey(). But what I want to do is to get the private and public key from pkey directly into a variable, preferable in the PEM format. I already looked around but couldn't find the right function. Any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really need the PEM representation, then `PEM_write_bio_RSA_PUBKEY()` and `PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey()` (along with their `read` counterparts) are the functions you want; give them memory BIOs to have them write into a memory buffer.

You can create a memory `BIO` by invoking e.g.

```
BIO * b = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
```

and get the memory buffer by invoking

```
void * buf;
BIO_get_mem_ptr(b, &buf);
```

You can also create a memory `BIO` around existing memory by invoking e.g.

```
BIO * b = BIO_new_mem_buf(buf, 9001)
```

but the resulting `BIO` will be read-only.

Comment: How would I export to PKCS#1 DER (without the base64 stuff). What about some other formats (PKCS#8, PKCS#12, etc.).

Comment: @Uri For DER you want the `i2d_*` family of functions, which take a memory buffer as second argument. To export in PKCS8, you want either `PEM_write_bio_PKCS8PrivateKey` or `i2d_PKCS8PrivateKey_bio` depending on format. To export a PKCS12 object, you want `i2d_PKCS12_bio`, but you have to first construct the PKCS12 with `PKCS12_create`.

Comment: Also according to the openssl documentation RSA_generate_key is now deprecated and instead you should use RSA_generate_key_ex - http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_generate_key.html